# Add object to json file - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to add an object to a very large JSON file in Node.js (but only if the id doesn't match an existing object). What I have so far:

**example JSON file:**

```
[
  {
    id:123,
    text: "some text"
  },
  {
    id:223,
    text: "some other text"
  }
]
```

**app.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');     
var jf = require('jsonfile')
var util = require('util')    
var file = 'example.json'

// Example new object
var newThing = {
  id: 324,
  text: 'more text'
}

// Read the file
jf.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
  // Loop through all the objects in the array
  for (i=0;i < obj.length; i++) {
    // Check each id against the newThing
    if (obj[i].id !== newThing.id) {
      found = false;
      console.log('thing ' + obj[i].id + ' is different. keep going.');
    }else if (obj[i].id == newThing.id){
      found = true;
      console.log('found it. stopping.');
      break;
    }
  }
  // if we can't find it, append it to the file
  if(!found){
    console.log('could not find it so adding it...');
    fs.appendFile(file, ', ' + JSON.stringify(newTweet) + ']', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('done!');
    });
  }
})
```

This is *so* close to what I want. The only problem is the trailing `]` character at the end of the JSON file. Is there a way to delete it using the file system API or something? Or is there a much easier way to do exactly what I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The proper way to handle this is to parse the JSON file, modify the object, and output it again.

```
var obj = require('file.json');
obj.newThing = 'thing!';
fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(obj), function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: That would be the correct solution for small files but what if the file is very big?

Comment: Yeah, the file is very big. I'll edit my question to specify that.

Comment: If your file is very big, it should be line-delimited by record or something anyway.  Otherwise it becomes unmanageable and you have to do interesting hacks like you are attempting.  Besides, the package you're using to read this file reads the whole thing anyway.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer, if your file is big you shouldn't be reading the whole contents in memory as you currently do. So before thinking about how to append a record to such a file you should think about how to determine if the record id doesn't already exist. The `jsonfile` module still loads the entire file in memory so you have a problem at this stage. And if you already can afford loading the entire file in memory, then Brad's solution will help you.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. In any case, this code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer I didn't test it, it's there to give you the gist of what to do.  If you could explain what the error is, I could help you figure it out.  Did you specify the path to `file.json`?  Sometimes you have to use `./file.json`.  Did you `require('fs')`?  I added a callback so you can see the error.  Try that.

Comment: Yeah, I specificed the `./` and the `require('fs')`. All it did was minify my json file. No error messages.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer Ah, so it's working just fine then.  It read the file, and output it.  You added some code to modify your data?

Comment: If you want to insert the record you should push it into the existing array you have parsed from the file: `obj.push(newThing);`.

Comment: Ah right, yes it works now with the push! Thanks both.

Comment: Oh something you've missed out from my question though was that it checks if an object with a matching ID already existing. This code produces duplicates.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer I didn't realize that was the part in your question that you were stuck on.  In any case, you should post that as your own answer and accept your own answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

For my project I ended up using this code.

```
function appendJsonToFile(file, entry, key, callback){

        if(!_.isObject(entry)){
            return callback('Type object expected for param entry', null);
        }

        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data){

            if(err){
                return callback(err, null);
            }

            var json;

            try{
                json = JSON.parse(data);
            } catch(e){
                return callback(e, null);
            }

            if(!_.isArray(json[key])){
                return callback('Key "' + key + '" does not point to an array', null);
            }

            json[key].push(entry);

            fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(json), function (err) {

                if(err){
                    return callback(err, null);
                }

                callback(null, file);
            });
        });
    }
```